# Sub-selection of JQuery not working as expected

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have on a page several `div`s in the manner of

```
<div id="{{ myId }}" class="typelist"><!-- content goes here --></div>
```

Also, there is a list of "links" in the following manner:

```
<a href="#" onclick="showThis({{ myId }})">{{ myDescriptiveName }}</a>
```

The correspondent JS-part looks like this:

```
function showThis(id) {
    var divs = $('div.typelist');
    divs.hide();
    divs.find('#' + id).show();
}
```

What I want to do is, search for the div with the id `id` in the current selection and toggle it to 'visible'. I have understood now, that `find()` only searches for children and "grandchildren", which explains, why the above does not work as expected.

But, how do I properly find the desired `div`inside of the current selection? Googling did not produce any helpful information to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be

```
function showThis(id) {
    var divs = $('div.typelist');
    divs.hide();
    $('#' + id).show();
    //or divs.filter('#' + id).show();
    //or divs.filter('[id="' + id + '"]').show();
}
```

when you use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/), it looks for the descendants of the `divs` elements, but in your case the element you are looking for is among the `divs` elements.

In this case you need to use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead of [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/), but since in this case you have id you can directly use the [id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Comment: `filter()` was indeed what I was looking for.

As @AlexanderScholz implicates, the ID should be unique, but my thought was, that I already have a filtered set from the DOM, so the performance should be better, if i searched through this subset instead of the whole DOM tree.

Answer (score 1):

```
function showThis(id) {
    var divs = $('div.typelist');
    divs.hide();
    $('#' + id, divs).show();
}
```

This looks for the ID in your selection. But your ID should be unique anyway. So Arun P Johny's answer is the best.